Can't connect to MongoDB server with Tableau or Python but can with Compass on Windows 10
It was extremely easy accessing MongoDB server by pasting conn string into MongoDB Compass on Windows 10 but when it comes to Python or Tableau it returns errors
For Python its either timout or:
Configuration Error: The DNS query name does not exist: _mongodb._tcp.mac88stage.sui9p.mongodb.net.


from pymongo import MongoClient

# Connection URI
uri = "mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER.NAME.mongodb.net/"

client = MongoClient(uri)

db = client.db_name

collection = db.table_name

top_10_rows = collection.find().limit(10)

for row in top_10_rows:
    print(row)


When creating DSN (following this guide: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/tutorial/create-system-dsn/)
I get Unknown MySQL Driver Host
For Tableau followed the standard guide:
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_mongodb.htm
added driver and connector into relevant folders in Tableau but getting similar errors to Python

I do know Mongo DB can cache connections on the same instance, see this answer  with what may be a similar issue. Not 100% sure this is the cause though.

Did you try adding google DNS server under the DNS section
Add 8.8.8.8 in your DNS entry and try to connect.

Thanks for a reply Rajnessh. Tried but didnt help
